# Why does this If condition in VB.NET always evaluates to true and the same code in C# does not

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, vb6

I have same If condition in VB and C# as follows

```
  Dim str As String = "aaa"
    If (str.IndexOf("bbb")) Then
        Console.WriteLine("aaa")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
```

The same code in C#

```
 string str = "aaa";
  if(str.IndexOf("bbb") > -1)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("aaa");
   }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

First of all you can not write if statement in C# with just IndexOf as condition you need to put > -1 to make it accept a boolean. But where as in VB you can write that,compiler does not give any error,and even if IndexOf returns -1 If always evaluates to true in VB. Why is this happening?

Comment: What does this question have to do with VB6?

Comment: Because it's not the "same code"? You've inserted an explicit comparison and a *magic number* - what made you choose -1?

Comment: It has everything to do with VB6.  A Basic version where True equals -1.  Lots of good reasons for that, it avoids having to distinguish between the mathematical and logical And and Or operators.  It had to be carried forward into VB.NET to give programmers a shot at porting their code.  Program with Option Strict On for a while to let the compiler tell you that you are getting it wrong.  But beware it is easy to get used to and it will be hard to turn it back off again.

Comment: If you're going to use incredibly sloppy VB 'shortcuts', then you had better know what those shortcuts are doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because VB.NET provides an implicit conversion from the integer value to `Boolean`, it considers any non-zero integer expression to be `true`, similar to C/C++. C# won't let you do that. It insists that you provide a proper `bool` expression, hence the `>` operator.

If you were to use the same expression in VB.NET as you are using in C#, it would work the same.